# UIScrollView with multiple image horizontal

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, imageview

I need to make horizontal scrolling of 2 images in a view. I have achieved single image scrolling very well, but not getting for showing multiple image in scrollview. I have attached code for single scroll. Below is the attach image what i need to achieve.[image]

```
galleryScrollView = [UIScrollView new];
galleryScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
galleryScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
galleryScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
galleryScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
galleryScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
galleryScrollView.delegate = self;
galleryScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
[backView addSubview:galleryScrollView];

for(int i=0;i<resultDict.count;i++) {

    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x= galleryScrollView.frame.size.width *i;
    frame.origin.y=0;
    frame.size=galleryScrollView.frame.size;

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
    imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    NSString *imageString = [[resultDict valueForKey:@"ImageURL"] objectAtIndex:i];
    [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageString]];
    [galleryScrollView  addSubview:imageView];
}
galleryScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(galleryScrollView.frame.size.width * resultDict.count, galleryScrollView.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: in screen u want to show one image at time ?

Comment: No, I want to show 2 images in one screen

Comment: than u need to add view between images , it may help you to scroll images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

As you can see Above i took two sample images with background color blue and gray. in an scroll View. and in coding Part one flot Variable for current Scroll X-position of scrollview "currScrollXPosition"

```
 [self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width*4, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
[self.scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];

currScrollPosition = 0;
```

now you just have to give action to those buttons 
for previous button

```
- (IBAction)prevBtnClicked:(id)sender {

if(currScrollPosition > 0 ){
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(currScrollPosition-self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.contentOffset.y)
                         animated:YES];
    currScrollPosition = currScrollPosition-self.scrollView.frame.size.width;

}}
```

and for next button

```
- (IBAction)nextBtnClicked:(id)sender {

if(currScrollPosition < self.scrollView.contentSize.width){
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(currScrollPosition+self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.contentOffset.y)
                         animated:YES];
    currScrollPosition = currScrollPosition+self.scrollView.frame.size.width;

}}
```

surely it will work for you. Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you want two images on one screen, but the frame you make for each image is the size of the screen, and the origin is off.  To change the origin replace

```
frame.origin.x= galleryScrollView.frame.size.width *i;
```

with

```
frame.origin.x= galleryScrollView.frame.size.width *i/2;
```

Likewise you will also need to change the `frame.size`.

Comment: i don't see you set frame for your scrollview and width of uiimageview is not correct:

Answer (score 0):

i don't see you set frame for your scrollview and width of uiimageview is not correct, it must

```
frame.origin.x= galleryScrollView.frame.size.width/2 *i
```

and

```
galleryScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(galleryScrollView.frame.size.width/2 * resultDict.count, galleryScrollView.frame.size.height);
```

But, i think it's better if you use UICollection to show your product.